# Extracing values from json using json path java

Tags: jsonpath

I am trying to write a json path query to extract the values from a json which my tests return. My sample json would look like this:

```
{
    "childNode1":{
    "name":"Node to be validated"
    },    
    "unusedNode":"Submitted",
    "childNode2":[
    {
    "tester2":"value to be tested against"
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to validate name in `childNode1` if the `tester2` value in `childNode2` matches with my input. How to get the value of name in `childNode1` if `tester2` value matches with my input.

I tried the following json path queries:

```
$..childNode2..tester2..childNode1..name

$..childNode2..tester2..name
```

But only null value is getting returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of tester2 with following jsonpath:

```
String childNode2Value = jsonPath.get('$.childNode2..tester2')

if (childNode2Value.equals("your test input"))
{
 String childNode1Name = jsonPath.get('$.childNode1.name')
}
```

A handy way to evaluate jsonPath can be found [here](http://jsonpath.com/)

And jsonPath reference can be seen [here](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).